# JSF two required h:inputText (exclusive or)

Tags: java, jsf

I would that 2 imputText are required: if email is valued, the mobilephone is not required and vice versa.
How can I do?

Thanks.

```
                <h:inputText required="true" id="usEmail" size="20"
                    value="#{rwUser.usEmail}" />

                <h:message for="usEmail" style="color:red" />


                    <h:outputText value="#{msg.mobilephone}" styleClass="textMessage" />

                <h:inputText id="usMobilephone" size="20"
                    value="#{rwUser.usMobilephone}" />

                <h:message for="usMobilephone" style="color:red" />
```

Comment: I guess you want something like if there is a value in email then user can not type phone no. Is that right??? Or he can type the phone no but that is not necessary.???

Comment: @Abhinav I think he wants that at least one of the two must be filled

Answer (score 8):

Several ways.

- Bind the `UIInput` components to the view and in the required attribute of the first, check the submitted value of the second and in the required attribute of the second, check the value of the first (components are namely processed in the order as they appear in the view).

  ```html
  <h:inputText binding="#{usEmail}" ... required="#{empty usMobilePhone.submittedValue}" />    
  <h:inputText binding="#{usMobilePhone}" ... required="#{empty usEmail.value}" />
  ```
- Check the presence of the submitted value in the request parameter map.

  ```html
  <h:inputText binding="#{usEmail}" ... required="#{empty param[usMobilePhone.clientId]}" />    
  <h:inputText binding="#{usMobilePhone}" ... required="#{empty param[usEmail.clientId]}" />
  ```

  Or with hardcoded client IDs:

  ```html
  <h:form id="form">
      <h:inputText id="usEmail" ... required="#{empty param['form:usMobilePhone']}" />    
      <h:inputText id="usMobilePhone" ... required="#{empty param['form:usEmail']}" />
  ```
- Use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:validateOneOrMore>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOneOrMore).

  ```html
  <h:inputText id="usEmail" ... />    
  <h:inputText id="usMobilePhone" ... />
  <o:validateOneOrMore components="usEmail usMobilePhone" showMessageFor="@all" />
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `<o:validateOneOrMore>` of the OmniFaces is what you need. See also [the `<o:validateOneOrMore>` showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOneOrMore).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `binding` to get a reference from one component to another:

```
<h:inputText required="true" id="usEmail" binding="usEmail" 
    size="20" value="#{rwUser.usEmail}" required="#{empty usMobilePhone.value}" />    

<h:inputText id="usMobilephone" size="20" value="#{rwUser.usMobilephone}" 
    binding="usMobilePhone" required="#{empty usEmail.value}"/>
```

Note that `usEmail.value` refers to the `UIComponent` object corresponding to the inputText, not the managed bean value.

If that doesn't work you may need to replace `value` with `submittedValue` because of the JSF lifecycle - `UIComponent.value` doesn't get set until after validations succeed, and  `submittedValue` is what actually got posted with the form submit.